# How can i add DocumentID in CollectionReference of cloud firestore? Using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store documentID in my cloud_firestore_database using flutter. I have made a authentication for every User ,so that the data of every User can store individually.Data storing in database in the following  way(Student entry => auth(UserId) => vault =>documentID(xj23yvbfvbnbjgkb) => User details)

```
// collection reference

 CollectionReference vaultCollection =  Firestore.instance.collection('student entry').document(uid).collection('vault');
 vaultCollection.document().setData({
    "Entry-time": date,
    'image': url,
    'fname': name,
    'year': year,
    'purpose': visiting,
    'vehicleno': vehicleno,
    'contact': contact,
   'Exit-time': "unknown",

   'docId'://How can i add documentID ?

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DocumentReference returned from `document()`. It contains the randomly generated id before the document is actually added.

```
DocumentReference doc = vaultCollection.document();
doc.setData({
  ...
  'docId': doc.documentID
});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help it's working .I have documentID in my database

Comment: Can pls help me in my first question ?Which I have asked earlier. I want to stop user update their detail after updating first time and restrict them to update more time